# ¿Se puede usar Docker para distribuir un software con todas sus configuraciones?

Tags: docker

tengo el siguiente escenario:

Tengo un software que instalo en mis clientes pero ojalá fuera instalar solamente (siguiente-siguiente-instalar), hay que hacer un millón de cosas en el ordenador de cada cliente para que el software funcione, por lo tanto...

Se puede usar esa tecnología Docker (o cualquier otra) para:

1. Instalar un software (administrativo desarrollado en Visual FoxPro)
2. Instalar una impresora PDF (que requiere el software del punto 1)
3. Instalar SQL Server (el motor que utiliza el software del punto 1)
4. Crear directorios y ficheros (que requiere el software del punto 1)
5. Crear accesos directos (para ejecutar el software del punto 1)

En resumen: ¿es posible crear un contenedor con "todos los juguetes" que un software necesita para su funcionamiento y poder distribuirlo en todos los clientes?

De ser posible lo anterior, ¿Qué requisitos necesitaría cada cliente?

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Además de poder hacer todo eso que requieres, podrás contenerizar tu aplicación, con lo cual, lanzar docker y tienes tu app instalada y lista para funcionar. Los requisitos los puedes ver en la web de docker. Pero debes tener en cuenta que docker se usa sobre todo sobre imagenes de linux, dicho lo cual, si estamos hablando de apps que corren bajo windows no creo que puedas hacerlo. Siempre te queda la opción de InstallShield o similar